# Javascript order of referencing

Tags: javascript

What order does the following statement run? Does the runtime execute it from right to left?

```
  length = i = test = output = null;
```

Comment: How would you test in what order this executes? (Or is that a really stupid question; sorry, it's been a very long day (and night)...)

Comment: There isn't really a way to "test" the order in which they execute. You could open a javascript console (probably by hitting Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + I in your browser right now) and paste in the above code. Then when you tested the values of each variable, you would find them all to be null.
Interestingly, since there is only one operator ("="), and since it works from right to left, the only way that this could work would be from right to left, otherwise, everything would have a value of length, including null... wait, what?

Comment: That was my assumption, but I assumed I must be missing something (perhaps) obvious...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, since an [assignment expression](http://es5.github.io/#x11.13) is not a [lefthand-side expression](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2) itself, the nesting is

```
(length = (i = (test = (output = null))));
```

It is executed from outside-in, solving references left-to-right (first getting the `length` variable, then evaluating the right side, which is getting the `i` variable and evaluating …). That means `output` is the first variable that is getting assigned to, then `test`, then `i`, and last `length`: "right-to-left" if you want. Since the assignment operator always yields its right operand, everything will be assigned the same (innermost, rightmost) value: `null`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Even better that you've linked to the spec.

Answer (score 3):

> Does the runtime execute it from right to left?

Yes.

```
foo = {
    set a() {
        console.log('a');
    },
    set b() {
        console.log('b');
    },
    set c() {
        console.log('c');
    },
    set d() {
        console.log('d');
    }
};
foo.a = foo.b = foo.c = foo.d = 'bar';
```

produces:

```
d
c
b
a
```

in the console. This order is necessary because each assignment relies on the return value of the previous assignment:

```
foo.a = foo.b = foo.c = foo.d = 'bar';
```

is equivalent to:

```
foo.a = (foo.b = (foo.c = (foo.d = 'bar')));
```

However ***it is not equivalent to***:

```
foo.d = 'bar';
foo.c = foo.d;
foo.b = foo.c;
foo.a = foo.b;
```

The return value of `a = b` is `b`. This is especially important to remember should you choose to implement accessors and mutators.

What this means is that my previous example **is equivalent to**:

```
foo.d = 'bar';
foo.c = 'bar';
foo.b = 'bar';
foo.a = 'bar';
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it executes from right to left.
The value of everything is now null.

Answer (score 1):

That single line assignment is equivalent to this

```
output = null;
test = output;
i = test;
length = i;
```

Comment: OK, but how does this answer the question?

Comment: @j08691: I expect this multiline script to make clearer what's the order of execution...

Comment: How does this not answer the question?

Comment: What happens with you people? I imagined that this sequencial equivalence would make clearer that order of execution is from right to left.

Comment: no, this is not correct. the return value of an assignment is the value being assigned. this is especially important when dealing with accessors and mutators.

Comment: @zzzzBov: yes, in this scenario are equivalent.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi, I try to avoid knowingly misleading possible future readers who won't understand the difference.