# Assignment operators，why the result is -3?

Tags: javascript, c

In the JavaScript language

```
var a=3;
a += a -= a*a;  //-3
```

In the C language：

```
int a=3;
a += a -= a*a;  //-12
```

Comment: In C the result is undefined. In JS: https://es5.github.io/#x11.13.2

Comment: your statement is equivalent to `a = a + (a = a - a*a) ;` - does that make it easier to understand

Comment: …wherein the inner (right) assignment doesn't really matter, because the variable is overwritten by the outer (left) assignment right away, so it's `a = a + (a - (a * a))`

Comment: @Kay: Any references for your first statement? I'd like to add it in my answer.

Comment: @Bergi, in C an expression like `a = a + (a = a - a * a)` might "fill in" the `a`s in any order whatsoever the compiler deems useful. `a = 3 + (a = 3 - 3 * 3)` or `a = a + (a = 3 - 3 * 3)` (assignment first) is both allowed. Compare https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sequence_point&oldid=685791988#Sequence_points_in_C_and_C.2B.2B. Even lhs references can be evaluated before the rhs.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JS, operands of an operator such as `+`, `=`, `*` or `+=` are always evaluated left-to-right. So what happens here is, step by step:

```
var a = 3;             // a = undefined
a += (a -= a*a);       // a = 3
a = 3 + (a -= a*a);    // a = 3
a = 3 + (a = 3 - a*a); // a = 3
a = 3 + (a = 3 - 3*a); // a = 3
a = 3 + (a = 3 - 3*3); // a = 3
a = 3 + (a = 3 - 9);   // a = 3
a = 3 + (a = -6);      // a = 3
a = 3 + -6;            // a = -6
a = -3;                // a = -6
-3;                    // a = -3
```

In contrast, your C code does evaluate the left-hand side `a` only after the right-hand side operand is evaluated, at which point `a` has a value of `-6`, which is then added to itself. However, the C language leaves this as undefined behaviour and does not define an specific order for the evaluations, so you only experienced this as an artifact of your compiler. See @Kay's comments for details.

Answer (score -2):

JavaScript assignments traverse left to right.

You are telling JS:

```
3 += 3 = 6
6 -= 3*3 = -3
```

I can't think of a permutation of this that would result in -12...

Comment: That might have the same outcome, but is not what happens here.

Comment: Btw, `var a = 3; a -= a*a; a += a` results in `-12`

Comment: Touche -- your answer much more accurately describes what's going on here.

Had to do some testing to make sure. I guess it's actually more accurate to say, however, that assignment operators in JS are evaluated right to left, no?

Comment: [kinda](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18495990/1048572) :-) The assignments happening right-to-left is a side effect of the operators being evaluated left-to-right (outside-in).