# Why does this code create the object, but still treats it as undefined?

Tags: javascript, global, shared-memory, iife, use-strict

I don't understand why doesn't this code work as expected:

```js
"use strict";
window.obj.prop = (() => {
    window.obj = { myobj: true };

    return "value";
})();
```

[image]

I always thought that `=` operator first evaluates whatever it is to the right of it (IIFE in this snippet), and then assigns the result to whatever is to the left of it (`window.obj.prop` in this snippet). Looks like something different happens here though.

If the interpreter first evaluates the IIFE, then it should create `window.obj` before setting its `.prop`, which shouldn't result in `TypeError`. On the other hand, if the interpreter first checks presence of `prop` in `window.obj` (and fails with `TypeError` because `window.obj` is undefined), then it shouldn't evaluate the IIFE, which shouldn't create `window.obj`.

What I observe is that both `window.obj` is created **and** `TypeError` is thrown, which doesn't make sense to me.

---

Notes:

- `"use strict"` thrown in "just in case", the snippet works similarly without it;
- the snippet works the same both in browser (Chrome 80.0) and Node.js (v13.3);
- the `window.obj` (or `global.obj` in Node) object doesn't exist prior to this snippet being run;

Comment: No, the [evaluation of the `=`  operator is left-to-right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18495990/1048572) like all other operators. Yes, [it's confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32342809/1048572) when the rhs changes what the lhs refers to :-)

Comment: @vatz88 Yes, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wrong. This should throw an exception even *before* evaluating the rhs. It's a bug (or at least, deviation from the spec) in the engine. See https://es.discourse.group/t/rhs-evaluation-in-assignment-to-unresolvable-reference/310.

---

<s>[That's just how it works](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation):</s>

1. The left-hand side is evaluated to a reference
2. The right-hand side is evaluated to a value
3. The value is [put in the reference](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-putvalue), which throws an error if the reference cannot resolve its base value

I don't know why they didn't bother checking the reference before evaluating the right-hand side, however this behaviour is consistent with a setter property throwing.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Non-compliance to the spec, that's very interesting